# I have set up a small flask webpage but in only runs on localhost while I would like to make it run on my local network python3.7

Tags: python, flask, localhost, wifi, python-3.7

I have set up a small flask webpage but in only runs on localhost  while I would like to make it run on my local network, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my 2 cents on this, I just did some research, there are many suggestions online...

Adding a parameter to your app.run(), by default it runs on **localhost**, so change it to `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')` to run on your machines IP address.

Few other things you could do is to use the flask executable to start up your local server, and then you can use `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` to change the default IP which is **127.0.0.1** and open it up to non local connections.

The thing is you should use the app.run() method which is much better than any other methods.

Hope it helps a little, if not good luck :)